# Use CSS to order list items top to bottom, left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

Updates at bottom

Looking to order items in a fixed height unordered list where horizontal expansion is allowed, but would like the items to arrange top to bottom first, then left to right. This is to keep the height of the table cell within which they are contained to a set height, but allow it to expand horizontally.

For example:

```
<td>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</td>

1 4
2 5
3
```

Is this possible with CSS only?

Each list item is a fixed height and width.
The number of elements in the list is unknown and variable.
The desired height of the list is fixed (3x li height).

I have no trouble getting a fixed width list with vertical expansion to work, but the transpose seems difficult. I am using jQuery on the page if needed but would prefer CSS only option.

**Update:** I think I found a solution that may work. [Fiddle using transform](http://jsfiddle.net/RXFXy/1/)

**Update2:** Working! I changed alignment within the cell, used transform rotate and transform origin and relative positioning to get everything working. Perhaps not the most elegant solution but I'll take it! [Complete Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/2apCT/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [**`column-count`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).

```
ul {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/n85cx/) - seems to produce the desired results.

Comment: The only solution without the need for JQ or server-side scripting. Should be noted it doesn't work for <IE10 though.

Comment: Looking to keep it to a maximum of three rows, regardless of the number of items. Maybe I'll try column count combined with rotate

Answer (score 1):

For the fixed height list, you can achieve this by combining CSS columns (see the answer by JoshC) and [writing-mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/) property (currently supported in IE, with limited support back to IE7).

The following **[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s5LM9/20/)** seems to work even in IE7:

```
/* CSS for modern browsers */
ul {
    height: 6.1em;
    column-width: 6em;
    column-gap: 0;
    column-fill: auto;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
}

/* IE9 writing-mode workaround */
ul {
    word-spacing: -.5em;
    writing-mode: tb-lr;
}

li {
    writing-mode: lr-tb;
    word-spacing: normal;
}

/* 'magic' workaround of IE7 limitation */
*+html ul {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    filter: flipV();
}

*+html li {
    display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    filter:flipH();
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This is working close to perfectly, the only remaining problem is that the table cell this list is contained within is expanding to what would be the complete width of a single row if they were not presented in columns. This problem is happening in Chrome. Working great in IE even though the order is different.